# How to use a varibale from a function into some other block of the same class

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to use the member of some function in the same class to check with the condition in some other block in the same class:

```
class SomeClass{

let whatToDo: string;

public result(){  // want to implement the code but not able to.The only condition is that I want to call it from the Final() function only.

        if ( // the value of latest is not equal to 'addition' ){
             return the value of latest
           }
        else if (// if the value of latest is not equals to 'multiplication'){
              return latest;

        else return;
}

}
public addition(){
    this.whatToDo = 'addition';
     this.Final(this.whatToDo);
      return;
}

public multiplication(){
     this.whatToDo = 'multiplication';
     this.Final(this.whatToDo);
      return;
}

private Final(type:string){

       latest = type;
 }
}
```

I have tried implementing the above result() as follows: But it does not works.

```
result(){
 if(this.Final.latest != 'addition') {
   return this.Final.latest;
}
 else if (this.Final.latest != 'multiplication') {
    return this.Final.latest;
}
else return;
}
```

Note: please ignore typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access via `this`, you need to make it a member of the class and declare it just `whatToDo: string`

Also make your `latest` as a member of the class too.

Something like this.

```
class SomeClass {

   whatToDo: string;
   latest: string;

   public result() {  

      if (this.latest !== 'addition'){
           return the value of latest
      } else if (this.latest !== 'multiplication'){
            return latest;
      } else {
            return;
      }

   }

   public addition() {
       this.whatToDo = 'addition';
       this.Final(this.whatToDo);
   }

   public multiplication() {
       this.whatToDo = 'multiplication';
       this.Final(this.whatToDo);
   }

   private Final(type:string){ 
       this.latest = type;
   }

}
```

Comment: Can't I use directly the Final function call in the `result()` function definition and check the result that `Final()` returns? provided If I add return `this.latest` in the `Final()` function definition.

Comment: What do you thing, what it must return? Where you need to keep the latest value?

Comment: I think you need to call a function to store the last key and use last key member to check. Your function only takes a logic of keeping the last key

Comment: okay got it , I can only use the member variable of that function? correct?

Comment: Not function, but class member variable. You can make it private also.